# Sitecore multisite with AD membership configuration

Tags: active-directory, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I have to build two websites running on a single sitecore instance. Both the sites using same AD domain(mydomain) but 2 different user groups(users1, users2). Here it is `"((memberOf=cn=users1,OU=Groups,OU=mydomain Accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=org)(memberOf=cn=users2,OU=Groups,OU=mydomain Accounts,dc=mydomain,dc=org))"`.

Users1 has access to both *Site1* and *Site2*. But users2 has access to site2 only. How to configure membership provider in this case? Creating two different provider with same domain threw me an error saying "Duplicate domain entry". can someone help me with this?

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

You only need one provider to import all the users and one provider to import all groups into Sitecore from your Active Directory domain. Once they are being pulled in via the appropriatly configured membership and role providers you can then use Sitecore's security model to lock down which group has access to which site.

You can set and monitor users access rights via the `Security Editor` and `Access Viewer`.

See the Sitecore documentation for further details on how to do this [Assign access rights to a security account](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assign_access_rights_to_a_security_account)